# ListView is mixing edittexts

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listView` with `edittexts` and `checkboxes`. I understand that i need to **store information** about each item, to set up again when getting the view for each item, because it recycle the java objects for the `view`. Following this idea I've made a list for each input type. So, i have a `ArrayList` of strings for `edittext`, and one of Boolean for `checkboxes`. The `checkboxes` are working fine when scrolling, but `edittext` is not.

```
private List<String> restore;

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    }

   input= convertView.findViewById(R.id.input);


   input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            restore.set(position, editable.toString());

        }
    });

    input.setText(restore.get(position));

}
```

I mention the fact that the listview is inside a fragment, but i don't think this is the problem.I don't know what to tell more, to help me/you to figure out a solution...

Comment: `but edittext is not.` how it works, and how it should?

Comment: As per me its never the good idea to put an `EditText` inside `ListView` item. Its hard to manage Although you can make it works  by getting view and save the previous data . But i think you should come up with a better design approach . Get input with Dialog mayBe.

Comment: Expected: To see the text where it was written. Actual: The text is copying to other edittexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `setXXX()`, method `addTextChangedListener` will not replace old value with a new value, but instead will add another TextWatcher to `EditText` each time you call it.

So you need to `removeTextChangedListener` before adding new one. But to remove it, you have to store it in a variable.

Solution:

1. Use `ViewHolder` pattern.
2. Add a `TextWatcher` variable to the `ViewHolder`.
3. Before adding new `TextWatcher` remove old one.
4. Write your new created `TextWatcher` to the `ViewHolder` after you create it, and only then use it in `addTextChangedListener`.

---

Alternatively to using ViewHolder, you may just create another `List<TextWatcher>`, and store TextWatchers there.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the `position`. You're using wrong position while setting value in `restore` list. Make use of `setTag` method to hold the position

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        }

        final EditText input = convertView.findViewById(R.id.input);
        input.setTag(position);  //this will hold the actual position of view


        input.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(input));

        input.setText(restore.get(position));

    }

    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

        EditText editText;
        public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText){
            this.editText = editText;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            restore.set(editText.getTag(), editable.toString());  //here you use the position of view which is being edited
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think it is the same position. If I set.the text for the edittext before the listener, this will causes problems.

Comment: what problem?? when you load `listview` its `getView` has latest position say 5 and I'm editing 0th item `edittext` in this case you should update restore list's 0th position not 5th.